# Any way to obtain what TFS element someone worked on?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, changeset

I just received instructions to add the TFS element number to the comment of any changeset I commit. I find this mesure redundant because I already have to assign the TFS element to my changeset.

I was told it was because it was hard to obtain the list of TFS element a developper worked on.

Isn't there a smarter way to obtain this information?

Comment: When you say "element", do you mean "work item"?

Comment: Hum, that was a really bad translating from my part. Yes, I meant "work item".

Answer (score 2):

With using Work Item links between a Changeset and Work Items (the recommended approach - assuming your are using TFVC), you could write a bit of code against the TFS API, or a query against the TFS Data Warehouse to retrieve all changesets by Developer A, then traverse the WI links to find all WI's.